# Wifi has IP by DHCP but no internet access

Tags: networking, debian

I have installed a new USB Wifi network card in Debian 9.
After configuring it, the router assigns me an IP via DHCP but I don't have internet access.
It is the Alpha Network AWUS036NH (Ralink RT3070 Chipset) Wifi network card.
It is on a Debian 9 without a graphical environment.

I have installed the firmware-ralink package and it is using the rt2800usb driver.

I have tried the next commands:

iwconfig

```
eth1 no wireless extensions.

eth0 no wireless extensions.

wlan0 IEEE 802.11 ESSID:"CAMIONES"
Mode:Managed Frequency:2.437 GHz Access Point: 74:AC:B9:21:3C:E5
Bit Rate=1 Mb/s Tx-Power=20 dBm
Retry short limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
Encryption key:off
Power Management:off
Link Quality=70/70 Signal level=-37 dBm
Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:1 Invalid misc:4 Missed beacon:0

lo no wireless extensions.
```

ifconfig

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 10.80.4.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.80.4.255
ether 4c:02:89:12:c0:be txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 5002 bytes 631414 (616.6 KiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 5510 bytes 882802 (862.1 KiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
device memory 0xd0600000-d06fffff

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
loop txqueuelen 1 (Local Loopback)
RX packets 6146 bytes 509679 (497.7 KiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 6146 bytes 509679 (497.7 KiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.200.18 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.200.255
ether 00:c0:ca:5a:00:60 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 8 bytes 1170 (1.1 KiB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 58 bytes 7704 (7.5 KiB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0 10.80.4.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eth0
10.80.4.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 eth0
169.254.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 U 1000 0 0 eth0
192.168.200.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 wlan0
```

traceroute -i wlan0 8.8.8.8

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  *^C
```

I have tried to add a static route so that when I use wlan0 it will find its gateway:

```
route add default gw 192.168.200.1 dev wlan0
```

The rule is added but it does not work and I also lose internet access through eth0

ping -c2 -I wlan0 [www.google.fr](http://www.google.fr)

```
PING www.google.fr (216.58.209.67) from 192.168.200.18 wlan0: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- www.google.fr ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1032ms
```

Contents of the configuration files:

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 80.58.61.250
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 80.58.61.254
```

/etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid CAMIONES
wpa-psk pass
gateway 192.168.200.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.200.1
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

```
network={
ssid="CAMIONES"
psk="pass"
}
```

I have tried connecting to another router and have the same problem.

What problem can I have with the configuration?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your default route is set to go out via eth0 so all traffic will leave the eth0 interface, unless you have a **specific(non default) route** set to go out via wlan0.

Try this and see if you get a response:

route add -net 8.8.8.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.200.1 dev wlan0

ping 8.8.8.8

Comment: Okay, that has worked for me. Although I don't understand why I can't ping my gateway: ping -c2 -I wlan0 192.168.200.1. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you can ping 8.8.8.8 after adding the static route then traffic is passing through 192.168.200.1. It might be your gateway is not responding to icmp.